# How to identify tab space in xslt

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have working in xml to html conversion. But the table is a typeset format. In between text tab space presented.

input format

```
15  30  35
12  40  65
```

Expected output

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>65</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the tab separated data in some element (e.g. `data` is assumed to contain the tab separated data in below sample) and you use XSLT 3 you can use the `tokenize` function first to split of the data into lines mapped to rows of the table and then to split up each row into the cell data:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <table>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="tokenize(., '\r?\n')" mode="row"/>
          </table>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]" mode="row">
      <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="tokenize(., '\t')" mode="cell"/>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]" mode="cell">
      <td>{.}</td>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjimZ